# How to replace a word, but only if it is not in combination with another one?

Tags: python, replace

I have a (made up) sentence that reads

> Children MUST do their homework and MUST NOT use their phones during that time. They MUST do their chores without whining.

I would like to replace

- `MUST` → `**MUST**`
- `MUST NOT` → `**MUST NOT**`

A generic `.replace("MUST", "**MUST**")` (and the same for `MUST NOT`) will not work. In order to account for the combined words, my current ugly solution is to

- replace `**MUST NOT**` with  `zkjhziufyslkdjfsdyotfjsgkj`
- replace `MUST NOT` with `zkjhziufyslkdjfsdyotfjsgkj`

(at that point old `**MUST NOT**` and new `MUST` are handled)

- same operation for the plain `MUST` (with a different replacement)
- replace `zkjhziufyslkdjfsdyotfjsgkj` with `**MUST NOT**`
- replace [the replacement word for `MUST`] with `**MUST**`

This will work but is ugly. (I do not take into account some edge cases where there is only one or multiple != 2 instances of `*`)

**Is there a more elegant way to say *"replace [something] with [something else], except for [something aword]"*?**

Comment: What exatcly is your problem here? There are lot of solutions for this kind of task, but I do not understand the problem. Do you have trouble because `must` is a substring of `must not`, which can lead to things like `**MUST** NOT`?

Comment: @Andreas: yes, and to `****MUST** NOT**`

Answer (score 2):

You might use a pattern with an optional group, and replace with the full match between double `**` like `**\g<0>**`

```
\bMUST(?: NOT)?\b
```

- `\bMUST` A word boundary to prevent a partial match and match `MUST`
- `(?: NOT)?` Optionally match a space and `NOT`
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sn5KxZ/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\bMUST(?: NOT)?\b"
s = "Children MUST do their homework and MUST NOT use their phones during that time. They MUST do their chores without whining."
subst = r"**\g<0>**"
result = re.sub(pattern, subst, s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
Children **MUST** do their homework and **MUST NOT** use their phones during that time. They **MUST** do their chores without whining.
```

---

Or asserting whitespace boundaries to the left and the right side:

```
(?<!\S)MUST(?: NOT)?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtIQyS/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing `'MUST NOT'` first and then `' MUST'` with space before  the string?

```
sentence.replace('MUST NOT', '**MUST NOT**').replace(' MUST', ' **MUST**')
# Children **MUST** do their homework and **MUST NOT** use their phones during that time. They **MUST** do their chores without whining.
```

Comment: Oh that's a good one, thanks. I would add  a one liner to get rid of the previous `**` before applying yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* for checking if `**` are already present:

```py
import re
s = 'MUST NOT - **MUST NOT** - MUST - **MUST**'
re.sub(r'(?<!\*\*)\bMUST\b( NOT\b)?(?!\*\*)', r'**MUST\1**', s)
#'**MUST NOT** - **MUST NOT** - **MUST** - **MUST**'
```

A live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IafwFk/1)